# The wordpress loop doesn't return the post structure

Tags: wordpress

I just installed the latest Wordpress build (3.5.1) and when I add the loop as usual it doesn't return the normal structure.

This is my php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php
        $pageid = get_query_var('page_id');
        $postid = $post->ID;
    ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="wppost" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>

      <div class="wpentry"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="wpnavigation">
          <?php posts_nav_link('','F&ouml;reg&aring;ende sida','N&auml;sta sida'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
      <div class="wppost" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><?php _e('Inl&auml;gget hittades inte'); ?></h1>
      </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

And that usually works. But all it does now is return only what's in < p >-elements.

It doesn't return wppost, the_title, wpentry or anything except what I have written in the post itself (only text so far).

Is this something new or what am I doing wrong? I've done exactly this for a few years and it's worked so far. I'm stumped.

This is from the header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" /> <!-- leave this for stats please -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&format=link'); ?>
<?php //comments_popup_script(); // off by default ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="maincontainer">


            <div id="header">
                <a href="#" title="Descending Chaos"><img alt="Descending Chaos" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/liveheader.png" /></a>
            </div>

            <div id="top">
                <div id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=','sort_column=menu_order'); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="social">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="Descending Chaos on Spotify" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/spotlogo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="Descending Chaos on Reverbnation" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/reverblogo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="Descending Chaos on Facebook" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/facelogo.png" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title=""><img alt="Descending Chaos on YouTube" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/youlogo.png" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

EDIT: Updated the original post with more code.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `<?php print_r( $post ); ?>` before the loop, you should be able to see the query. If it doesn't return anything, then there's a problem with the query. The code you've got here looks fine.

Comment: It returns the unformatted content, i.e. the text in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to my development site and it works there, so I don't think it is a problem with your code.

Try putting `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before the loop. Maybe `$wp_query` and `global post data` got modifed before your loop and needs to be restored.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't help. Are you using the same Wordpress version?
I've updated the original post with the content from the header. As well as a few lines of code that preceeded the loop itself. Though I doubt they make much difference since commenting them out doesn't help either.

Comment: Where is that loop located? In which template?